# Cannot return Self in protocol extension

Tags: ios

I am trying to return a default value from a protocol extension. I've tried the solution below and I am getting the following error: `Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call`. If I try to create an initializer in the extension I get errors about infinite recursion. Is there a reasonable solution for this?

Generally, the goal is to have structs that conform to `MyFunStructProtocol` but make it easy to provide a default/fallback value.

```
public protocol MyFunStructProtocol: Codable {
    associatedtype T
    
    var text: String { get set }
    var num: Int { get set }
    var value: T  { get set }
    
    static var fallback: T { get }

}

extension MyFunStructProtocol {
    static func defaultValue() -> Self {
        var x = Self()
        x.text = "fallback"
        x.num = 55 // default
        x.value = Self.fallback
        return x
    }
}
```

Comment: Not `defaultValue()`. Just [``default``](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1409234-default).

Comment: @Jessy I don't think it helps or has something to do with the question.

Comment: @lazarevzubov That's a mode of thinking adopted by people who feel a lot of pain when being corrected. Some of us live our lives by Cunningham's Law and consider it disrespectful to not have someone tell us when we're wrong.

Comment: @Jessy SO is not for code review, it's for asking questions that are otherwise not covered with documentation. The author of the question didn't ask for corrections on code style, and your comment is not likely to reach its goal. Moreover, your comment is a distracting noise for other people, who are looking for answers on similar questions.

Comment: Agree to disagree, @lazarevzubov. People never get better at overlooked areas when we have to silo our criticism such that they never go looking for what they actually need. Feel free to edit the code, instead. It's within your rights hereI, but won't lead to the myelination that the OP needs to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem there is that you're trying to use an initializer (`Self()`, where `Self` is `MyFunStructProtocol`), but `MyFunStructProtocol` doesn't declare any. In order it to work you need to declare some way of creating objects in the protocol. For instance:

```swift
public protocol MyFunStructProtocol: Codable {
  init()
  // The rest is unchanged.
}
```

All types conforming to `MyFunStructProtocol` will have to implement `init()` of course.

(You can declare any initialization or factory method inside the protocol. The idea here is that the protocol must ensure a way to create an object to be able to create the object.)

As for the second part of your question, you can declare additional initializers in extension, but you'll need at least one that is declared on the protocol itself.